# How to get notified when a user leaves home in the SetSDK?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the SetSDK to show users the available bike share count at their nearby station whenever they leave their home. I'm following the example available in the [pod documentation](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK) but am not getting the notification. Here is my code,

```
SetSDK.instance.onDeparture(.home) { notification in
    // below is my code using the notification
    let bikeStationCount = getAvailableBikes(stationsNear: notification.location)
    showNotification(withCount: bikeStationCount.count, atStation: bikeStationCount.station)
}
```

But I'm not getting my app to show any notification, any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct. The only thing to keep in mind is that the SetSDK will learn the user's home over time, with most users it usually takes 1-2 days for it to have enough certainty to call a place Home.

Have you had a chance to let the SDK learn long enough that it is giving you notifications now?

Hey, cool use-case!

Comment: Yes! I have been working on it the past couple days and started getting notifications today. It would be super helpful to be able to test those as a developer without waiting.